# Simulink cross-compilation succeeded, application not working

Tags: c, matlab, makefile, cross-compiling, simulink

I am currently trying to compile a Simulink model for a SoC board that is running a Linux OS. I am able to compile and run applications successfully for this board making my own makefiles, which are really very simple.

The cross-compiler I am using is the
environment-setup-cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

Also, generating c code from a Simulink model and applying my makefile works as well. (With very simple simulink models)

The problem is when I try  to generate code and also compile the simulink model with the following options:

ert.tcl

toolchain: automatic (GNU)
for: faster builds

This generates a binary that is working but I have to modify the makefile in order to compile the code with my cross-compiler. The cross-compilation works but when I try to run the application in the SoC board I get the following error:
-sh. ./application file not found

Here is the makefile:

```html
###########################################################################
## Makefile generated for Simulink model 'simmod'. 
## 
## Makefile     : simmod.mk
## Generated on : Tue Sep 11 14:57:43 2018
## MATLAB Coder version: 4.0 (R2018a)
## 
## Build Info:
## 
## Final product: $(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ANCHOR)/simmod
## Product type : executable
## Build type   : Top-Level Standalone Executable
## 
###########################################################################

###########################################################################
## MACROS
###########################################################################

# Macro Descriptions:
# PRODUCT_NAME            Name of the system to build
# MAKEFILE                Name of this makefile
# COMPUTER                Computer type. See the MATLAB "computer" command.

PRODUCT_NAME              = simmod
MAKEFILE                  = simmod.mk
COMPUTER                  = GLNXA64
MATLAB_ROOT               = /opt/MATLAB/R2018a
MATLAB_BIN                = /opt/MATLAB/R2018a/bin
MATLAB_ARCH_BIN           = $(MATLAB_BIN)/glnxa64
MASTER_ANCHOR_DIR         = 
START_DIR                 = /home/hector/Documents/Qt/DA_AMiRo/Devices/Reflective_Operator/Matlab_Reflective_Operator/temp
ARCH                      = glnxa64
SOLVER                    = 
SOLVER_OBJ                = 
CLASSIC_INTERFACE         = 0
TGT_FCN_LIB               = ISO_C
MODEL_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_SFCNS = 0
MODELREF_LINK_RSPFILE_NAME = simmod_ref.rsp
RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ANCHOR   = ..
C_STANDARD_OPTS           = -mfloat-abi=hard -std=gnu99 -pedantic -fwrapv #-std=c99 
CPP_STANDARD_OPTS         = -fwrapv

###########################################################################
## TOOLCHAIN SPECIFICATIONS
###########################################################################

# Toolchain Name:          GNU gcc/g++ v4.4.x | gmake (64-bit Linux)
# Supported Version(s):    4.4.x
# ToolchainInfo Version:   R2018a
# Specification Revision:  1.0
# 
#-------------------------------------------
# Macros assumed to be defined elsewhere
#-------------------------------------------

# C_STANDARD_OPTS
# CPP_STANDARD_OPTS

#-----------
# MACROS
#-----------

WARN_FLAGS         = -Wall -W -Wwrite-strings -Winline -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align
WARN_FLAGS_MAX     = $(WARN_FLAGS) -Wcast-qual -Wshadow
CPP_WARN_FLAGS     = -Wall -W -Wwrite-strings -Winline -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align
CPP_WARN_FLAGS_MAX = $(CPP_WARN_FLAGS) -Wcast-qual -Wshadow

TOOLCHAIN_SRCS = 
TOOLCHAIN_INCS = 
TOOLCHAIN_LIBS = 

#------------------------
# BUILD TOOL COMMANDS
#------------------------

# C Compiler: GNU C Compiler
CC = arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc #gcc

# Linker: GNU Linker
LD = arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ #g++

# C++ Compiler: GNU C++ Compiler
CPP = arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ #g++

# C++ Linker: GNU C++ Linker
CPP_LD = arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ #g++

# Archiver: GNU Archiver
AR = ar

# MEX Tool: MEX Tool
MEX_PATH = $(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)
MEX = "$(MEX_PATH)/mex"

# Download: Download
DOWNLOAD =

# Execute: Execute
EXECUTE = $(PRODUCT)

# Builder: GMAKE Utility
MAKE_PATH = %MATLAB%/bin/glnxa64
MAKE = "$(MAKE_PATH)/gmake"


#-------------------------
# Directives/Utilities
#-------------------------

CDEBUG              = -g
C_OUTPUT_FLAG       = -o
LDDEBUG             = -g
OUTPUT_FLAG         = -o
CPPDEBUG            = -g
CPP_OUTPUT_FLAG     = -o
CPPLDDEBUG          = -g
OUTPUT_FLAG         = -o
ARDEBUG             =
STATICLIB_OUTPUT_FLAG =
MEX_DEBUG           = -g
RM                  = @rm -f
ECHO                = @echo
MV                  = @mv
RUN                 =

#----------------------------------------
# "Faster Builds" Build Configuration
#----------------------------------------

ARFLAGS              = ruvs
CFLAGS               = -c $(C_STANDARD_OPTS) -fPIC \
                       -O0
CPPFLAGS             = -c $(CPP_STANDARD_OPTS) -fPIC \
                       -O0
CPP_LDFLAGS          = -Wl,-rpath,"$(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)",-L"$(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)"
CPP_SHAREDLIB_LDFLAGS  = -shared -Wl,-rpath,"$(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)",-L"$(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)" -Wl,--no-undefined
DOWNLOAD_FLAGS       =
EXECUTE_FLAGS        =
LDFLAGS              = -Wl,-rpath,"$(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)",-L"$(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)"
MEX_CPPFLAGS         = -R2018a -MATLAB_ARCH=$(ARCH) $(INCLUDES) \
                         \
                       CXXOPTIMFLAGS="$(C_STANDARD_OPTS)  \
                       -O0 \
                        $(DEFINES)" \
                         \
                       -silent
MEX_CPPLDFLAGS       = LDFLAGS=='$$LDFLAGS'
MEX_CFLAGS           = -R2018a -MATLAB_ARCH=$(ARCH) $(INCLUDES) \
                         \
                       COPTIMFLAGS="$(C_STANDARD_OPTS)  \
                       -O0 \
                        $(DEFINES)" \
                         \
                       -silent
MEX_LDFLAGS          = LDFLAGS=='$$LDFLAGS'
MAKE_FLAGS           = -f $(MAKEFILE)
SHAREDLIB_LDFLAGS    = -shared -Wl,-rpath,"$(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)",-L"$(MATLAB_ARCH_BIN)" -Wl,--no-undefined

#--------------------
# File extensions
#--------------------

H_EXT               = .h
OBJ_EXT             = .o
C_EXT               = .c
EXE_EXT             =
SHAREDLIB_EXT       = .so
HPP_EXT             = .hpp
OBJ_EXT             = .o
CPP_EXT             = .cpp
EXE_EXT             =
SHAREDLIB_EXT       = .so
STATICLIB_EXT       = .a
MEX_EXT             = .mexa64
MAKE_EXT            = .mk


###########################################################################
## OUTPUT INFO
###########################################################################

PRODUCT = $(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ANCHOR)/simmod
PRODUCT_TYPE = "executable"
BUILD_TYPE = "Top-Level Standalone Executable"

###########################################################################
## INCLUDE PATHS
###########################################################################

INCLUDES_BUILDINFO = -I$(START_DIR) -I$(START_DIR)/simmod_ert_rtw -I$(MATLAB_ROOT)/extern/include -I$(MATLAB_ROOT)/simulink/include -I$(MATLAB_ROOT)/rtw/c/src -I$(MATLAB_ROOT)/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I$(MATLAB_ROOT)/rtw/c/ert

INCLUDES = $(INCLUDES_BUILDINFO)

###########################################################################
## DEFINES
###########################################################################

DEFINES_BUILD_ARGS = -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DMAT_FILE=0 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0
DEFINES_IMPLIED = -DTID01EQ=0
DEFINES_STANDARD = -DMODEL=simmod -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DMODEL_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_SFCNS=0 -DUNIX

DEFINES = $(DEFINES_BUILD_ARGS) $(DEFINES_IMPLIED) $(DEFINES_STANDARD)

###########################################################################
## SOURCE FILES
###########################################################################

SRCS = $(START_DIR)/simmod_ert_rtw/simmod.c

MAIN_SRC = $(START_DIR)/simmod_ert_rtw/ert_main.c

ALL_SRCS = $(SRCS) $(MAIN_SRC)

###########################################################################
## OBJECTS
###########################################################################

OBJS = simmod.o

MAIN_OBJ = ert_main.o

ALL_OBJS = $(OBJS) $(MAIN_OBJ)

###########################################################################
## PREBUILT OBJECT FILES
###########################################################################

PREBUILT_OBJS = 

###########################################################################
## LIBRARIES
###########################################################################

LIBS = 

###########################################################################
## SYSTEM LIBRARIES
###########################################################################

SYSTEM_LIBS =  -lm

###########################################################################
## ADDITIONAL TOOLCHAIN FLAGS
###########################################################################

#---------------
# C Compiler
#---------------

CFLAGS_BASIC = $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)

CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS_BASIC)

#-----------------
# C++ Compiler
#-----------------

CPPFLAGS_BASIC = $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)

CPPFLAGS += $(CPPFLAGS_BASIC)

###########################################################################
## INLINED COMMANDS
###########################################################################

###########################################################################
## PHONY TARGETS
###########################################################################

.PHONY : all build buildobj clean info prebuild download execute


all : build
 @echo "### Successfully generated all binary outputs."


build : prebuild $(PRODUCT)


buildobj : prebuild $(OBJS) $(PREBUILT_OBJS)
 @echo "### Successfully generated all binary outputs."


prebuild : 


download : build


execute : download
 @echo "### Invoking postbuild tool "Execute" ..."
 $(EXECUTE) $(EXECUTE_FLAGS)
 @echo "### Done invoking postbuild tool."


###########################################################################
## FINAL TARGET
###########################################################################

#-------------------------------------------
# Create a standalone executable            
#-------------------------------------------

$(PRODUCT) : $(OBJS) $(PREBUILT_OBJS) $(MAIN_OBJ)
 @echo "### Creating standalone executable "$(PRODUCT)" ..."
 $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PRODUCT) $(OBJS) $(MAIN_OBJ) $(SYSTEM_LIBS) $(TOOLCHAIN_LIBS)
 @echo "### Created: $(PRODUCT)"


###########################################################################
## INTERMEDIATE TARGETS
###########################################################################

#---------------------
# SOURCE-TO-OBJECT
#---------------------

%.o : %.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : %.cpp
 $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ANCHOR)/%.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ANCHOR)/%.cpp
 $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(MATLAB_ROOT)/rtw/c/src/%.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(MATLAB_ROOT)/rtw/c/src/%.cpp
 $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(MATLAB_ROOT)/simulink/src/%.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(MATLAB_ROOT)/simulink/src/%.cpp
 $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(START_DIR)/%.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(START_DIR)/%.cpp
 $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(START_DIR)/simmod_ert_rtw/%.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


%.o : $(START_DIR)/simmod_ert_rtw/%.cpp
 $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"


###########################################################################
## DEPENDENCIES
###########################################################################

$(ALL_OBJS) : $(MAKEFILE) rtw_proj.tmw


###########################################################################
## MISCELLANEOUS TARGETS
###########################################################################

info : 
 @echo "### PRODUCT = $(PRODUCT)"
 @echo "### PRODUCT_TYPE = $(PRODUCT_TYPE)"
 @echo "### BUILD_TYPE = $(BUILD_TYPE)"
 @echo "### INCLUDES = $(INCLUDES)"
 @echo "### DEFINES = $(DEFINES)"
 @echo "### ALL_SRCS = $(ALL_SRCS)"
 @echo "### ALL_OBJS = $(ALL_OBJS)"
 @echo "### LIBS = $(LIBS)"
 @echo "### MODELREF_LIBS = $(MODELREF_LIBS)"
 @echo "### SYSTEM_LIBS = $(SYSTEM_LIBS)"
 @echo "### TOOLCHAIN_LIBS = $(TOOLCHAIN_LIBS)"
 @echo "### CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)"
 @echo "### LDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS)"
 @echo "### SHAREDLIB_LDFLAGS = $(SHAREDLIB_LDFLAGS)"
 @echo "### CPPFLAGS = $(CPPFLAGS)"
 @echo "### CPP_LDFLAGS = $(CPP_LDFLAGS)"
 @echo "### CPP_SHAREDLIB_LDFLAGS = $(CPP_SHAREDLIB_LDFLAGS)"
 @echo "### ARFLAGS = $(ARFLAGS)"
 @echo "### MEX_CFLAGS = $(MEX_CFLAGS)"
 @echo "### MEX_CPPFLAGS = $(MEX_CPPFLAGS)"
 @echo "### MEX_LDFLAGS = $(MEX_LDFLAGS)"
 @echo "### MEX_CPPLDFLAGS = $(MEX_CPPLDFLAGS)"
 @echo "### DOWNLOAD_FLAGS = $(DOWNLOAD_FLAGS)"
 @echo "### EXECUTE_FLAGS = $(EXECUTE_FLAGS)"
 @echo "### MAKE_FLAGS = $(MAKE_FLAGS)"


clean : 
 $(ECHO) "### Deleting all derived files..."
 $(RM) $(PRODUCT)
 $(RM) $(ALL_OBJS)
 $(ECHO) "### Deleted all derived files."
```

Comment: Have you checked the binary is in the appropriate location in the SoC board?

Comment: Hi, yes. After a "ls" command I can see the application there but it doesn't run. Maybe the binary is corrupted or was not properly created?